# Magento 2: How can I add sku under product name on minicart for each product?

Tags: magento2, attributes, mini-cart

I can't find the phtml template for the minicart in the header, I think actually that the information like name, price, quantity etc are rendered with knockout js.

I want to add brand attribute value and sku under the name of each product.

How can I do that? Where are the files that I should override

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have to override the following template

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

and create a plugin for the function `getItemData()` of the class

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/AbstractItem.php
```

so you can provide the additional data to the template. Check this [post](https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/get-a-product-attribute-in-mini-cart-magento-2/) for more details about how you can extend the mini cart.

Comment: thanks, the post you linked it was helpful, it works adding the value from custom attribute for every product

Comment: What if I want 2 custom attributes, brand and some other. What should I change in the plugin files?

Comment: Add your other custom attribute at catalog_attributes.xml and also in the aroundGetItemData() function. Finally display it in the template default.html like is done for manufacturer.

Comment: I don't know exactly how should i return both values in aroundGetItemData(). Because i have the var $data and I don't understand exactly what is stored here..

Answer (score 2):

Override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

in `app/design/frontend/your_vendor/your_theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

find below code

```
<strong class="product-item-name">
    <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</strong>
```

and replace above code with this

```
<strong class="product-item-name">
    <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_sku"></a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko text: product_sku --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</strong>
```

Now run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command

For adding more product attributes in minicart, please refer `protected function doGetItemData()` in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php`